# MDL checkbox issue: don't want the label to activate the checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, material-design

I have a Material Design Lite checkbox whose label includes a link to Ts&Cs; but clicking on the link activates the checkbox. The code looks like this:

```
<label mdl class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox-1">
    <input mdl type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="mdl-checkbox__input" [(ngModel)]="loginRegisterData.termsConditions" #termsConditions (keyup.enter)="clickRegisterButton()">
    <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">I agree to the <a (click)="setVisiblePanel(5)" class="mouseHand">Terms and Conditions</a></span>
</label>
```

I don't really want the link to activate the checkbox. I have tried various renaming `label`s to `div`s, moving `div`s outside `label`s and so on, but haven't found a solution that looks decent.

I have checked on the MDL website, and it seems there is no standard way to configure checkboxes in this way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Put the link in a separate span outside of the label, and then set the label's width to 'auto' so that it doesn't take up the whole line. (and align the link using vertical-align:middle)

```
<label mdl class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox-1" style="width:auto">
  <input mdl type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="mdl-checkbox__input" [(ngModel)]="loginRegisterData.termsConditions" #termsConditions (keyup.enter)="clickRegisterButton()">
  <span class="mdl-checkbox__label">I agree to the </span>
</label>
<span class="mdl-checkbox__label" style="vertical-align: middle"><a (click)="setVisiblePanel(5)" class="mouseHand">Terms and Conditions</a></span>
```

see fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/yn8Ltt56](http://jsfiddle.net/yn8Ltt56)